# Website shows elements in different places - same browser - different machines

Tags: css, browser

I have this website that I'm making for someone (immo-deal.be) and it shows certain elements in different places on different machines, but the browser being used (IE 8.0) is exactly the same.

I don't understand how that is possible?  Anyone have an explanation?

Main element that moves is the flashing text moves up and bottom grey text moves up too.

Comment: I think http://doctype.com/ can help you more than here, you can show them with screen shots and all details you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the browser resolution is not the same on the both machines and there are HTML `block` elements `float`ing in a container without a `width` or with an extremely wide width.

Comment: so what do you recommend I do to keep same look and handle it so resolution is no longer a factor?

Comment: Sorry, the site hurted my eyes too much to have a closer look. At least the aforementioned is one of the common causes. Just give the container  a fixed width.

Comment: out of curiousity, what hurts your eyes about it? Color? Elements design?

Comment: Hurts my eyes too - you've got three yellows that clash with each other, red text on a yellow background, and flashing text.

Comment: I see, so better do something with the colors, thanks for the comments!!